# How to hide in WordPress meta tags in head section

Tags: wordpress, hide, html-head

Is there a way to hide meta tags in  section of the site made in WordPress?

I mean something like you check the code of the site by F12 in Chrome and you see wp-content/plugins and wp-content/themes. Is there a way to hide this?

I saw site based on the yootheme theme, that had something like that. But I don't know if it is some plugin or the theme itself got something like this built in.

Are there any plugins to achieve it, I didn't find any.

Comment: I think this is the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230411/how-to-hide-wordpress-details-from-view-source-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can usually be done by using a cache/minify/combine plugin, it will combine and minify all CSS and JS files in tojust a few files, and while doing so, it will create a more anonymized link in the source code.

This WP plugin should help:
https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/merge-minify-refresh/

Answer (score 0):

It's built into the theme or plugins you have installed.  You'd have to check the theme/plugin source code to see if there are any filters or actions for modifying what it inserts into the head section.  Search for the 'wp_head' action in your theme/plugins to see if it is inserting the meta tags.